# How to display events of google calendar in ListView on our android application?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I want to show already created events of google calendar in ListView on our android application. I want to fetch that events and wanted to show in ListView of our android application.

I created google calendar api from google console but this URL https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId showing (Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup) error.

Comment: Do what it says.  You've hit the limit for how much you're allowed to use per day.  Either you have a bug where you're making far too many requests (in which case fix it), or you've hit the level where you're going to have to sign up for (and possibly pay for) access.